# Append .wav metadata in MATLAB without reading/storing entire audio data

Tags: matlab, wav

Is there a way to append the 'Comment' metadata of a .wav file, using MATLAB, without having to read the whole audio data, modify the 'Comment' and then re-save the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

If .wav file has fixed length header, you can `fopen` it with append permission 'a', `fseek` to 'Comment' position and `fwrite` it byte-wise.

Comment: How do I ensure or check the fixed length header condition?

Comment: This is not right, if metadata is saved somewhere else, not as a part of wav file format.